# Notify on page when a user comes online IN DOM

Tags: php, mysql, notifications

I have this for adding the users online status when they are enter on my page and is working fine but i want this, when the online status goes "ON" on a specific user i want the script send a plublic notification with css in left corner "The user X is online now". Any help apreciated!

i have this Php process for the moment:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){
$tm=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$id=$user->data->id;
$q=mysql_query("UPDATE mls_users SET statusonline='ON',tm='$tm' WHERE id='$id'");
} else {
    echo "no user online";
}
$gap=5; # <-time
$tm=date ("Y-m-d H:i:s", mktime (date("H"),date("i")-$gap,date("s"),date("m"),date("d"),date("Y")));
$ut=mysql_query("UPDATE mls_users SET statusonline='OFF' WHERE tm < '$tm'");
```

Comment: Are you talking about pushing a notification to the browser, or on page load, show whether the user is on or not. If the former, then this is not a php question at all and more Javascript. It is a question of what you are using to build your front end. The best solution (imo) for pushing data to the browser is getstream.io.

Comment: Not on a page load.. pushing a notification to the browser when a user comes with the status "Online"..

Comment: The scope required is beyond a simple answer. You need a Javascript framework and DOM elements to push to. Then, either periodic calls to an api on your server, or an open socket. Honestly, you're far better off spending time searching on Google for a tutorial then getting an answer here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Update your code & add a variable:

```
From database you can find those users whose status is on line.
```

For public notification, (using ajax) you can check which users' status is"online='On'" & refresh the DOM element where you are showing the notification.

Comment: This is not what the questioner is looking for. It's a live push that is wanted. Although I agree this is far simpler.